# About systems of nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem: we have a metal plate whose temperature is now given by $T(x,y)=(x^2-4)(y^2-1) $. Denote the position of robot at time t by $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$. To ensure the robot is always increasing temperature, want $r'(t)= \nabla T(r(t))$, for all t. Interpret as a system of (non-linear) ODEs. The answer should have the form $x'(f(x,y), y'g(x,y)$ for some functions f and g.

How is nonlinear from linear ODE? How to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, the position of the robot is vector-valued, so I shall write $\mathbf r$ instead of just $r$.

We have $\mathbf r = (x,y)$ where we now think of $x,y$ as functions of time $t$, i.e.

$$\mathbf r (t) = \big(x(t),y(t)\big)$$

Compute

$$\nabla T = \bigg(\frac{\partial T}{\partial x},\frac{\partial T}{\partial y}\bigg) = \big(2x(y^2-1), 2y(x^2-4)\big)$$

So the system of ODE we want is

$$\frac{d\mathbf r}{dt} = \nabla T\big(\mathbf r (t)\big) \implies \begin{cases}\dfrac{dx}{dt} = 2x(y^2-1) \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt} = 2y(x^2-4)\end{cases}$$

As you can see, the LHS is linear but the RHS has nonlinear terms, so the whole system is non-linear.

---

To go about solving it, you can divide one equation by the other to obtain

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y(x^2-4)}{x(y^2-1)}$$

and we can now separate it:

\begin{align}
\implies & \int \frac{y^2-1}{y} \, dy = \int \frac{x^2-4}{x} \, dx \\
\implies & \frac 12 y^2 - \ln (y) = \frac 12 x^2 - 4\ln (x) + \text{constant}
\end{align}

Comment: thanks! how is RHS nonlinear?

Comment: well, you have squared terms...?

Comment: For example, $2xy^2$ is non-linear